# Can birds pass diseases to humans through contact surfaces?

Tags: pathology, health, parasitology, hygiene

My friend asked me the following question. She has a pigeon nesting on her window and the pigeon often touches the window, and my friend also sometimes touches the window (e.g. open and close it). The question is does the touching of her and the pigeon in a common surface (the window) can transmit infections or disease from the pigeon to herself? Is there a risk letting the pigeon nest on her window pane?

Comment: But it's on the other side of the window?! So how is that the same surface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided she washes her hands after touching surfaces that came into direct contact with the pigeon, there shouldn't be any relevant health risks from touching this surface.

And just because it sound like the pigeon somehow is nesting WITHIN her apartment: Be aware that pigeons can carry mites that could spread within the apartment and infest plants. I would advise against having wild pigeons in the apartment!

EDIT:

Knowing the pigeon is outside, it's not 100% necessary to remove the nest. It depends on whether this window is used for venting and on the direction of air pressure. (does wind go in or out at this side of the house?). Also it depends on the visual cleanliness of the nest. Bird-droppings can potentially represent a health risk, as they can spread through the air, once they dry out, while potentially containing dangerous micro-organisms. Same with feathers that lie around.

So if wind regularly comes from the side of the nest, she could remove the nest for safety reasons, especially if the window is in the kitchen. Otherwise she can't overcome that guilt by blaming health.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The pigeon is nesting on the outer window pane and not inside the apartment. Is the risk of mites still relevant?